# Why does the Bremsstrahlung radiation intensity decrease linearly with photon energy?

Tags: x-rays

Why does the spectrum for Bremsstrahlung radiation decrease linearly with photon energy after a certain point (50 keV in the plot)?

[image: Plot of X-rays]

Comment: the article that has the plot you show also discusses how it emerges , in a complicated manner  as far as the dependence of variables https://physicsopenlab.org/2017/08/02/bremsstrahlung-radiation/

Comment: I used brem in my PhD experiment, $d(\gamma, p)n$, and I do not recall a linear decrease.

Comment: @annav Doesn't that formula explain how the kinetic energy of the incident electrons is lost/converted into Bremsstrahlung radiation, rather than explaining why there is a maximum photon energy, and why X-ray intensity profile decreases linearly with photon energy?

Comment: If you look at the lot of experimental figures, it is a qualitative plot, not a solution of the formula

Comment: The E in the formula is the energy of the radiating particle.

Comment: here is a plot of photon energies for different E https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Plot-of-bremsstrahlung-spectrum-for-end-pint-energies-of-12-14-16-45-50-55-60-and_fig3_257989624

Comment: This gives the Kramer formula which is what you are asking about https://folk.ntnu.no/floban/KJ%20%203055/X%20%20Ray/Bremsstrahlung.htm  , also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%27_law